# mysql query on class destruct

Tags: php, sql, class, mysqli, destructor

Is it OK to perform a mysqli query on a class __destruct function?

I heard somewhere it will not always finish the query or it won't work as expected.

For example:

```
class stackoverflow{
    function a() {
    }

    function b() {
    }

    function __destruct() {
        //mysqli query here
    }
}
```

Comment: your question says __destruct() method and your code __construct()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason why it shouldn't work as expected. However, it would help if you explained why you wanted to do so in the first place, **[there may be a better solution than what you have in mind](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)**

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you are better of creating your own method to carry out any work that needs to be done toward the end of the script and call it manually.

The principle reason for this in my view, is error handling.

According to the [online documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php):

> Attempting to throw an exception from a destructor (called in the time of script termination) causes a fatal error.

This means that should an error arise - for example - in your mysql query, a fatal error will shutdown your script.

a __destruct method may well be useful at times, but better used in situations that only require some simple hard-code, which is tested and not error prone.

Additionally, some servers may change various parameters during the shut-down phase. Such as the working directory.